# Ec primes with exponent prime of the form $19\cdot x^2+40\cdot y^2$

Tags: number-theory

Ec primes are primes of the form:

$(2^n-1)\cdot 10^d+2^{n-1}-1$ where d Is the Number of decimal digits of $2^{n-1}$.

Now I consider the n's leading to a prime or probable prime with n prime.

The Vector of n's leading to a prime or probable prime with n prime Is:

v=[2,3,7,19,67,79,359,2131,3371,331259]

$19$ $2131$ $3371$ and $331259$ are primes of the form $19\cdot x^2+40\cdot y^2$, according to Oeis sequence A139981.

Is particular striking the abundance of these primes in the Vector v?

Primes of the form $19\cdot x^2+40\cdot y^2$ are biquadratic forma?

$19$ $2131$ $3371$ $331259$ are primes of the form $19\cdot x^2+40\cdot y^2$ and contain the digit $1$.

The primes in the Vector which are not of that form, that Is 2, 3,7,67,79,359 does not contain the digit 1.

Comment: I do not think , it helps anything. But ec(n) cannot be prime , if $n$ is of the form $4k+1$ because then $ec(n)$ is disivible by $5$. Hence , $v$ can contain only primes of the form $4k+3$ (except $2$ of course).